# Copying element from one list to another in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, pass-by-reference

Let's say that I created two different lists:

```
listA = [0, 0, 0]
listB = [1, 1, 1]
```

I want to make the an element in listB refer to the same object as an element in listA. So that the element in both lists change together.

```
listB[2] = listA[0]
>>listB[2]
>>0

listB[2] = 2
>>listA[0]
>>2
```

However doing the above just passes the value of the elements, so the lists are still referring to individual objects. Is there a method or a different data structure that could give me the desired effect?

Comment: Coincidently, This is pretty much what already happens when you say `listA = listB` or visa versa. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) for details.

Comment: Just make `listA = listB`, two references to *one list*. You can't share references between ordinary list objects otherwise, no.

Comment: if you are working with objects you can assume that, but not for integers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think he only wants _one_ element in each list to correspond, not all of them.

Comment: @leaf: I know, but you can't do that, so there are no other options.

Comment: if the element is an immutable then changing it won't update it in other list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple idea to get you started, and also help you understand better what's going on:

```
>>> listA = [[0], [0], [0]]
>>> listB = [[1], [1], [1]]
>>> listA[0] = listB[0]
>>> listA
[[1], [0], [0]]
>>> listB[0][0] = 2
>>> listB
[[2], [1], [1]]
>>> listA
[[2], [0], [0]]
```

But be careful:

```
>>> listB[0] = [3]
>>> listB
[[3], [1], [1]]
>>> listA
[[2], [0], [0]]
```

You could write a class that makes this invisible so it looks more like a list and is easier to use without making mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.  You can either make `listA` and `listB` themselves be the same object, in which case *all* their indices will reflect any changes made to either, or you can make them separate objects, in which case *none* of their indices will reflect changes.  You can't make two lists that are "joined at the hip", sharing only some of their index references.

Suppose that the value of `listB[2]` is some object called `obj`.  When you do something like `listB[2] = 2`, you aren't changing `obj`; you are changing `listB` (by making its index 2 point to some other object).  So you can't make `listA[2]` "reflect" `listB[2]` unless `listA` and `listB` are the same object.  You can certainly make `listA[2]` and `listB[2]` refer to the same object, but that won't affect what happens when you do `listB[2] = 2`, because that operation won't affect that shared object at all.